# Round down/truncate large float

Tags: python

I use this following code to round down any float to 2 decimals.

```
(int((number)*100))/100
```

For example: `112.4423 > 112.44`, `100.3478 > 100.34 (not 100.35)`

Yes it does the job but not for a large float with more than 16 digits (which will be transformed into exponents like this `10000000000000000.0 > 1e+16`)

Is there a more practical way of round down a float which might fix this problem? and please tell me that am I providing enough information or not, Thanks.

Comment: If the numbers don't need rounding, `>=` would be the correct comparsion. So I don't see any problem.

Comment: A better way is to use `math.trunc(number * 100) / 100`.

Comment: Do all the numbers have more than 2 digits after decimal?

Comment: `10000000000000000.00000` and `10000000000000000.12345` is always translated into `1e+16` rounding then always end up with no decimals (.00).

Comment: The number `10000000000000000.12345` cannot be represented with 64 bit floating point numbers. That is no problem of your rounding.

Comment: If it can't, is there another way of getting an accurate number?